# GDB in DEV C++ stalls on cout

Tags: c++, gdb, cout, dev-c++

I've recently started programming in DEV C++ and I've come across an issue that searching the Googleshere for has yet to prove helpful.

In the following code, GDB "hangs" when it hits line 5, `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int tree = 9;
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    tree = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and runs just fine, but when stepping through it always gets stuck here and neither "Next line" or "Continue" seem to work.

Here's some output from the GDB window:

```
Starting program: C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\breakGDB.exe 
[New Thread 7300.0x2028]

->->new-thread
[New Thread 7300.0x2638]

->->new-thread

->->starting

->->breakpoints-invalid

->->frames-invalid

->->breakpoint 1

Breakpoint 1, 
->->frame-begin 0 0x40153d

->->frame-function-name
main
->->frame-args
 ()
->->frame-source-begin
 at 
->->frame-source-file
hello.cpp
->->frame-source-file-end
:
->->frame-source-line
5
->->frame-source-end


->->source C:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\hello.cpp:5:38:beg:0x40153d

->->frame-end

->->stopped

->->pre-prompt
(gdb) 
->->prompt

->->post-prompt

->->frames-invalid

->->starting

->->frame-begin 0 0x44d2f0

->->frame-address
0x000000000044d2f0
->->frame-address-end
 in 
->->frame-function-name
std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
->->frame-args
 ()

->->frame-end

->->stopped

->->pre-prompt
(gdb) 
->->prompt

->->post-prompt
Single stepping until exit from function _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E,
which has no line number information.

->->frames-invalid

->->starting

->->frame-begin 0 0x46cf10

->->frame-address
0x000000000046cf10
->->frame-address-end
 in 
->->frame-function-name
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
->->frame-args
 ()

->->frame-end

->->stopped

->->pre-prompt
(gdb) 
->->prompt
```

I'm quite new to GDB. Is this a feature of GDB? Have I got a setting wrong? What's going on here?

I've got my fingers crossed it's not some foolish error on my part.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and "solved" it by switching the compiler set from 64-bit Debug to 32-bit Debug.

Still need a solution for 64-bit.

```
// Dev-Cpp 5.11 TDM-GCC x64 4.9.2 Portable
```